# How to add a string from a textbox to a listview in another window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am trying to create a listview in the mainWindow and if the user want to add an item he first needs to open a menu window. From that window, he goes a window with a textbox. Upon clicking a button the string typed into the textbox should be added to the listview. The problem I encounter is that I cannot send the string to the mainWindow because the method in the textbox window needs to be non-static for it to read the contents of the textbox. Thus I cannot add the string form the textbox to the ListView from the mainWindow.

I have taken a look at how to send a string to the mainWindow without making it a static. I have tried:

```
MainWindow newWnd = new MainWindow();
newWnd.Show();
```

This does make the text from the textbox appear in the ListView but upon adding another item to the ListView the first one disappears. I could create a way to add the previous items to the new window but this will only work to a certain extend. I do not want to need to open a new window every time the user adds an item to the ListView. I want to add an item to the ListView from the original mainWindow.

My code:

MainWindow:
XAML:

```
<ListView Name="ingredientsList"/>

<Button Content="Add +" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

.cs:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Opens the menu window
            Menu popup = new Menu();
            popup.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void AddIngredient(string e)
        {
            ingredientsList.Items.Add(e);
        }
```

The menu window opens the textbox window (no code needed)

The textbox window:
XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Ingredient"/>
<Button Content="Add" Click="Add_Click"/>
<Button Content="Cancel" Height="25" Width="70" Margin="125,150,0,0" Click="Cancel_Click" IsCancel="True"/>
```

.cs:

```
 public void Add_Click()
        {

            Window.AddIngredient(Ingredient.Text);

        }

        private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: you are creating a new instance of the main window everytime an item is added to it? you should keep the instance and reuse it instead.

Comment: @Bizhan Can you please explain what you mean and how I can do that?

Comment: I think it's self explanatory, you are updating a property of an instance of a window which you throw away afterwards. Keep that object in memory so the added items are not lost. By keeping in memory I mean create a mainwindow variable and instantiate it only once instead of each time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use data binding to store the `TextBox` input in a dialog's property e.g. `Ingredient`. When the *Add* button is clicked, add this item to a public collection of your dialog e.g., `Menu.NewIngredients` and clear the `TextBox`.
Once the dialog is closed, you can add the new items of `Menu.NewIngredients` to the `ListView` using data binding:

*Menu.xaml.cs**

```
partial class Menu : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IngredientProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Ingredient",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata("Boom"));

  public string Ingredient
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(MainWindow.IngredientProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.IngredientProperty, value);
  }

  public List<string> NewIngredients { get; set; }

  public Menu()
  {
    this.NewIngredients = new List<string>();
  }

  public void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.NewIngredients.Add(this.Ingredient);
    this.Ingredient = string.Empty;
  }

  private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

**Menu.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="Window">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Ingredient}" />
    <Button Content="Add" Click="Add_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Cancel" Click="Cancel_Click" IsCancel="True"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IngredientsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Ingredients",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<string>)));

  public ObservableCollection<string> Ingredients
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>) GetValue(MainWindow.ResultsProperty);
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.ResultsProperty, value);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.Ingredients = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Opens the menu window
    Menu popup = new Menu();
    popup.ShowDialog();

    popup.NewIngredients.Foreach(this.Ingredients.Add);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Name="Window">
  <StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Ingredients}" />
    <Button Content="Add +" Click="Button_Click"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```